# codeigniter thumbnail not created with this code

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the following code but don't know why thumbnails are not created.

```
//UPLOAD IMAGE
    //some $config vars for image
    $config['upload_path'] = './images/models';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|tif';
    $config['max_size'] = '0';
    $config['remove_spaces'] = true;
    $config['overwrite'] = false;
    $config['max_width'] = '0';
    $config['max_height'] = '0';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    //upload main image
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('photo')){
        $e = $this->upload->display_errors();
        print_r($e);
    }

    $image = $this->upload->data();

    //print '<pre>';
    //print_r($image); exit;

    if($image['file_name']){
        $data['photo']  = "images/models/". $image['file_name'];
        $data['raw' ]   = $image['raw_name'];
        $data['ext']    = $image['file_ext'];
    }


    //create new image
    $config0['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config0['source_image'] = $image['full_path'];
    $config0['new_image'] = "images/models/"."front". $image['file_name']; // you can assign your image name and location
    $config0['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
    $config0['width'] = 320;
    $config0['height'] = 270;

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config0);
    if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
    {
    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }

    //end of new image



    $config3['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config3['source_image'] = $image['full_path'];
    $config3['new_image'] = "images/models/"."main". $image['file_name'];
    $config3['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
    $config3['width'] = 800;
    $config3['height'] = 600;

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config3);
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config3);
    $this->image_lib->resize();



    $config4['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config4['source_image'] = $image['full_path'];
    $config4['new_image'] = "images/models/"."third". $image['file_name'];
    $config4['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
    $config4['width'] = 185;
    $config4['height'] = 125;

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config4);
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config4);
    $this->image_lib->resize();


    //thumbnail creation start
    $config1['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config1['source_image'] = $image['full_path'];
    $config1['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config1['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
    $config1['width'] = 185;
    $config1['height'] = 125;

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config1);
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config1);
    if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
    {
    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }

    //THUMBNAIL ENDS
```

Comment: is there a reason you are loading the library 4 times instead of just re-initializing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It is almost like yours. Write errors in the comments.

```
//UPLOAD IMAGE
//some $config vars for image
$config['upload_path'] = './images/models';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|tif';
$config['max_size'] = '0';
$config['remove_spaces'] = true;
$config['overwrite'] = false;
$config['max_width'] = '0';
$config['max_height'] = '0';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

//upload main image
if(!$this->upload->do_upload('photo')){
    $e = $this->upload->display_errors();
    print_r($e);
}else{
    $image = $this->upload->data();

    //print '<pre>';
    //print_r($image); exit;

    if($image['file_name']){
        $data['photo']  = "images/models/". $image['file_name'];
        $data['raw' ]   = $image['raw_name'];
        $data['ext']    = $image['file_ext'];
    }

    $config1['source_image'] = $image['full_path'];
    $config1['new_image'] = "images/models/"."front". $image['file_name']; // you can assign your image name and location
    $config1['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
    $config1['width'] = 320;
    $config1['height'] = 270;

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config1);
    if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
    {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        return;
    }

    $config1['new_image'] = "images/models/"."main". $image['file_name'];
    $config1['width'] = 800;
    $config1['height'] = 600;

    $this->image_lib->clear();
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config1);
    if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
    {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        return;
    }



    $config1['new_image'] = "images/models/"."third". $image['file_name'];
    $config1['width'] = 185;
    $config1['height'] = 125;

    $this->image_lib->clear();
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config1);
    if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
    {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        return;
    }


    //thumbnail creation start
    unset($config1['new_image']);
    $config1['create_thumb'] = TRUE;

    $this->image_lib->clear();
    $this->image_lib->initialize($config1);
    if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
    {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        return;
    }
    echo "Ok";
}

//THUMBNAIL ENDS
```

Answer (score 2):

The way the Image Manipulation class was designed, is that if you want to use it more than once within the same script, you have to run:

```
$this->image_lib->clear();
```

between the images being processed.

This clears all the previous settings, and gives you a clean slate for the next crop/rotate/watermark/whatever...

Comment: That didn't help either, not after creating new image and create thumbnail

Comment: `image_lib->clear()` does NOT set all settings back to their defaults (which is what we might expect it to do). So, you might have to reset some defaults with each config. I can't remember all the details, but i know this issue leads to unexpected results when doing multiple image functions.

Answer (score 0):

The most common problem with server side file system writing operations are lack of permissions. At a glance the code looks good to me, can you check that your thumbmail directories are writeable, try with `chmod`-ing the directories `777`

Comment: directory is writeable, the create thumbnail works when i move the thumbnail create block just below file upload ( above creating another images) but it doesn't work when i place create thumbnail block at bottom, pls help

Answer (score 0):

This problem might be due to mismatch in path of the image create. Try using FCPATH constant before url. That might help..